# How to render widgets in product and category description in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, widgets, widget, template-directive

In Magento 2 we can add widgets to CMS pages and CMS blocks with a directive like this (assuming we created this custom widget with a module before):

```
{{widget type="Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\CustomWidget" some_addtribute="some-value"}}
```

When we add the same widget code in product or category description it is not rendered. So the output is the text string from above.

How can we extend Magento 2 in a way that it will render widgets in product or category descriptions as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of instantiating the object manager and filterprovider etc. in your template, consider this:

In your block class (`Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\CustomWidget`) include the dependencies in your constructor:

```
/**
 * Example constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $catalogOutputHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $catalogOutputHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->catalogOutputHelper = $catalogOutputHelper;
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

Now in your block class add a method to filter the input:

```
/**
 * @param string $description
 * @return string
 */
public function getFilteredContent(string $description)
{
    return $this->filterProvider
        ->getBlockFilter()
        ->filter(
            $this->catalogOutputHelper->categoryAttribute(
                $this->getCurrentCategory(),
                $description,
                'description'
            )
        );
}
```

I assume that `getCurrentCategory()` is a method you've already created.

Now in your template, you can simply do:

```
echo $block->getFilteredDescription($_description);
```

So now your template is neat and tidy and all dependencies and business logic are separated to you block class, as it should.

Comment: Thx for the explanation and the implementation example!

Comment: How can i achive this in category description?i have call static block within description but it is not working for me http://prntscr.com/ko5qyj

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I can answer that myself.

While there might be better approaches one of the easiest is to just get an instance of `FilterProvider` (and the `StoreMangerInterface`) in the template where the widget should get rendered and pass the output through the block filter of the `FilterProvider`.

So for the category description this would for example be the template
`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\category\description.phtml` which you should copy to your custom theme: `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\category\description.phtml`.

In it you can now replace

```
/* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description') ;
```

with something like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$filterProvider = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider');
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

echo $filterProvider->getBlockFilter()
     ->setStoreId($storeManager->getStore()->getId())
     ->filter(
         $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description')
      );
```

And you can do similar things in all templates where you want something to render widgets.

Comment: Don't use the object manager, but dependency injection instead

Comment: That sounds like a better solution. Can you elaborate it? I. e. show how it is done with DI and give a reason why it is the better? I would be really interested in it and obviously switch the accepted answer to yours then.