# Magento 2 Calling widget/template_filter in .phtml

Tags: magento2, widget

Where is the equivalent way of writing the following Magento 1 code for calling a custom widget in Magento 2.3.1?

```
Mage::getSingleton('widget/template_filter')->filter($_product->getData('variants'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to answer without knowing more on the affect you are trying to achieve but will something like this work

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162423/70343

Otherwise please can you add more detail on the task you are trying to achieve. There is always a possibility the same thing can be done differently in M2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually the link you posted is exactly what i needed.