# Insert Widget Catalog Product Link in Better Blog not showing on front end

Tags: widgets, content

We are using the Better Blog extension inside of Magento to create multiple posts for marketing. It uses the same Page Editor as Element->Pages on the Magento Admin Panel. In the editor you can add the widget, modify the widget as normal, but it doesn't show on the front end. I've tried clearing cache for front end and backend but nothing works.
Note: the Catalog Product Link widget does show on the front end if you create it in a Element->Page page, but if you create the exact same widget in the Better Blog extension it doesn't work.
I thought it might be the extension not linked to the root category where the products are but it is setup correctly. Any thoughts?
Below is what is showing in the editor. disabled.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific module, but it seems the output didn't pass the class
\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider. It's used to render widgets & variables with the curly braces.

Here's a similar question with a lengthy explainer: [How to render widgets in product and category description in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117447/how-to-render-widgets-in-product-and-category-description-in-magento-2)

HTH, Tom

Comment: Thank you Tom for your time looking into this! It ended up being a default price issue as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out from troubleshooting with other items. It is unfortunately an oversight by me. On each item in the Catalog->Products section there is a 'price' section. If this is empty, the widgets won't work. Magento allows you to default that value to empty if you want when you are mass uploading items.
On any of the pages or posts where you can use widgets, if you are using a product specific widget, the price has to be filled out even if it is set to $0.00. The page and editor won't throw any errors nor does the dev tool show any errors when you are adding the widget or on the page after you save.